# How do I incorporate data from a JSON to a widget in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I try to pass data from a json that I have in my assets to some widgets but I have not been able to know how, considering that the json is practically a list of maps. I appreciate your help in this regard. I enclose the main widget and json codes. In the first Column where the Text is and where the image is I want to pass respectively Projectname and image (assets / $ {image +}).

In this case I would need to know how to transform that data so you can use it in the widgets.

```
Swiper(
itemHeight: media.height * 0.4,
itemWidth: media.width * .6,
layout: SwiperLayout.TINDER,
itemCount: 39,

itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange,
      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF858585)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('Familia Arkani', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Image.asset('assets/arkani.png', height: 60, width: 60,),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('pray.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                  child: Text('Orar'),
                ),
                Switch(
                  value: isOrar,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    setState((){
                      isOrar = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],

            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('give.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                  child: Text('Ofrendar'),
                ),
                Switch(
                  value: isOfrendar,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    setState((){
                      isOfrendar = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('move.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                  child: Text('Movilizar'),
                ),
                Switch(
                  value: isMovilizar,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    setState((){
                      isMovilizar = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
},

control: new SwiperControl(),
),
  );
  }
}
```

**This is the JSON** 
This data is what I want to incorporate into some widgets.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Arkani", //aqui quiero añadir el dato nombreProy
   "image": "arkani",
   "lugar": "Asia del Sur",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Durán",
    "image": "duran",
    "lugar": "Quechua Panao",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Flores Diego",
    "image": "flores_diego",
    "lugar": "Amahuacas",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Garay Galvez",
    "image": "garay_galvez",
    "lugar": "Estados Unidos",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the dart core framework code.

1. You should do it first create assets folder the root folder. ( insert to your JSON file in assets)
2. Open the pubspec.yaml file and declare your JSON file.

   assets:
    assets/sample.json
3. You can use this code and access your JSON file.

   String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/$path.json')
4. Now you have JSON file as a string.
5. You can convert data string to JSON format.

   var jsonList = json.decode(data);
6. Finally, you create a class JSON model. ( you can choose JSON to dart or JSON serialization library)

   for (var item in jsonList) {
         print(Sample.fromJson(item));
       }

This solution will help you.
If you want full code, look at gist file => https://gist.github.com/VB10/34e97818f19f6bf0749fff8ffd1a5319

[image: local json parser]

Comment: Is the button necessary? In the first Column widget of my code, how do I call the "image" data in the Image widget and the "nombreProy" data in the Text widget?

Comment: Maybe not needed button just recall read request. if you want image data source in JSON file, define future builder and call readJsonFromLocalPath when it's done call image widget or declare your model in a state, call your request when request did call your image.(model == null ? Text("loading"): Image(source:model.property )